# Why has Newtonsoft [JsonIgnore] stopped working in asp core mvc

Tags: asp.net-core

Why is my property with a `[JsonIgnore]` showing in the returned result?

In fact why are all my Newtonsoft attributes not working?

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System;

namespace Namespace
{
    public class Model
    {
        [JsonIgnore]
        public string IgnoredProperty { get; set; } <-- IS NOT IGNORED
    }
}
```

Replacing it with `IgnoreDataMember` or `ScriptIgnore` doesn't work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because asp net core has, since Preview 6, [changed which default serializer it uses](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/try-the-new-system-text-json-apis/).

Either change it back by adding `.AddNewtonsoftJson()` to your MVC options.

```
services.AddControllers().AddNewtonsoftJson()
```

Or go to your models and start using the `System.Text.Json` serializer instead.

```
 using System.Text.Json.Serialization;
 // using Newtonsoft.Json; <- instead of this
```

Answer (score 0):

Please Add "System.Text.Json.Serialization" library then It will work fine.

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Text.Json.Serialization;

namespace MyApp.CommonModels
{
    public class PostCommonModel
    {
        public long Id { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string Title { get; set; }

        [JsonIgnore]
        public string Slug { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I use Newtonsoft, what worked for me is to use   [Newtonsoft.Json.JsonIgnore] before the propeerty to ignore.